# Reading a file on Lua

Tags: arrays, file, lua

I'm working on a Lua project for college, but this is the first time I'm seeing Lua, so I don't know everything my teachers asked me to do.

I need to read a file, we must say "text.txt", which its data are organized this way:

```
entry
{
--
name = "John",
--
sex = "M" ou "F",
--
age = 20,
--
}
```

Then I need to put this data in an array so I can use them later.

Does anyone know how to do it and can help me with this code?

Comment: what do the `--` represent? Can you provide an example where you have more than one entry?

Comment: @hjpotter92 The point is... I don't know, on the description there is only this, they didn't give me an example with more than one entry. I think the `--` is just to separate each type, which means it is there for nothing.

Comment: But it can also mean that the file could be one of the format here: https://pastee.org/65xyw

Comment: They said to me it will be given a text file coded in ASCII where each register will be on this format: `entry { ... }`. So I think this one on the middle is the one that represents how the entries are going to be. @hjpotter92

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This format is a subset of Lua syntax, so you should have a fairly easy time of parsing it, assuming you're allowed to use some library functions.

As far as the format of the file goes: `f{ ...}` is syntactic sugar for `f({...}` as a function call.
The rest of the stuff in the braces is comments (starting with `--`) and table fields (`age = 20,`)

So, for instance, the example above (with "M" where we had a choice) would parse as the function call `entry({name = "John", sex = "M", age = 20})` which is valid Lua code, and can be parsed with the functions `load(string)` or `loadfile(path` in the standard library.

---

To actually extract the data, you'll need to do something along these lines:

```
local filecontents = [the contents of your file as a string]
local entries = {}
do
  -- define a function that our data-as-code will call with its table
  -- its job will be to simply add the table it gets to our array. 
  local function entry(entrydata)
    table.insert(entries, entrydata)
  end

  -- load our data as Lua code
  local thunk = load(filecontents, nil, nil, {entry = entry})
  thunk()


end
```

Comment: The usage of `_ENV` is incorrect. The `_ENV` upvalue of the `thunk` function is created and set to default(`_G`) when `load(filecontents)` is executed; creating a local `_ENV` later does not affect it. You should use the fourth argument of [`load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load) instead, e.g. `local thunk = load(filecontents, nil, nil, {entry = entry})`.

Comment: Thanks! Been a while since I had to mess with environments in 5.2. Edited.

Comment: @qu4ntumcpa and @peterm, let me ask you one more thing: I use this following code to put each line of the string into a line of the table `for line in texto:gmatch("[^\r\n]+") do line = line:gsub("\n", ""); table.insert(data, line) end`, so I put this: `{name="Cassio",sex="M",age=19}\n {name="Paula",sex="F",age=19}` on the table. Now I'm trying to sort by name and print what's inside the table, but when I use `table.sort(data, function(x,y) return x["name"] < y["name"] end)` I get this: `attempt to compare two nil values`. What should I do? What's wrong?

Comment: @cfrancklin why would you want to split the string into lines? You can use the code in this answer to extract entries from the whole string.

Comment: @peterm because of on `thunk()` I'm getting this message error: "attempt to call local 'thunk' (a nil value)"

Comment: Like most library functions in Lua, if e.g. `load()` fails, it returns null and the error message. Try `thunk = assert(load(...))` and you should see the error `load` is giving you.

Comment: @qu4ntumcpa considering filecontent is `entry({name="Cassio",sex="M",age=19})
entry({name="Paula",sex="F",age=19})` and I used the exactly code you posted above, do you know why when I try to print entries.name, entries.sex and entries.age inside a `for ....... do` it only appears on the screen `name = nil ; sex = nil ; age = nil` for both "Cassio" and "Paula"? There isn't error messages anymore, but I'm getting nil as result.

Comment: @peterm I was getting an error message using the code on the answer, now I'm using it and there isn't anything wrong, except that Lua isn't recognizing the two names, sexes and ages and putting nil on the table.

Comment: @cfrancklin why do you print `entries.name`? `entries` is an array. Assuming you iterate over it like this: `for i, entry in ipairs(entries) do ... end`, try printing `entry.name`, `entry.sex`, etc. inside the loop.

Comment: @peterm using entry.name, entry.sex, etc I'm getting `attempt to index global 'entry' (a function value)`.